# Is it possible to add a reverb to already recorded audio on Android?

Tags: android, audio, android-audiorecord

Is it possible to add a reverb to already recorded audio on Android? Not during playing, but modify the file, by adding a reverb.
Any answers appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pull the audio file into Audacity using your computer with your phone connected in mass storage mode. If you can figure it out, the GVerb plugin should be the tool to use. Or a faux reverb using Echo would do well also.

If the audio file itself is a weird format, you may have to install the FFMPEG decoder into Audacity to import it properly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. The file is recorded in PCM format and I can pack it in MP4 container. But I want to add audio effect before packing into MP4 container. Is it possible to do this programmatically?

Comment: If you mean doing so in Audacity, you should be able to create what is called a Chain, which is basically its version of a Macro. Apply it to your .wav file or whatever filetype your phone records, and it should apply the reverb (though by the looks of it, this does not include third-party plugins like GVerb, but only the built-in ones like Echo), and then have it automatically export to...it looks like just Flac, MP3, Ogg or WAV formats are supported..

Comment: No, I do not mean to do so in Audacity. I want my Android application to record an audio and then add audio effect to the recording.

Comment: Ah! Hmm...I can't think of an extremely easy way... You'd probably have to search for a third-party app to do so, but the only ones I know about are paid-for and annoying to use (i.e. not programmatic at all). However, the one I use is [SPC - Music Sketchpad 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mikrosonic.SPC), which does allow you to import audio files and add all sorts of effects to them, and even dub them into larger works. I believe it may even have a record function as well. Take a look at the [demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mikrosonic.SPCDemo).